# Proper way to letterbox with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have an input source of 1280x720 that I want to convert into a 720x1280 video.  I want to letterbox the 1280x720 video so it maintains it's original 16/9 aspect ratio and has block box on the top and bottom of the video - with the video in the center.

This works for for scaling

`-vf "scale=720x1280"`

But i'm struggling to get the padding to work.  I've tried this with no success:

`-vf "scale=720x1280,pad=ih*9/16:ih:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"`

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to add "force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease"

    -vf "scale=720x1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=ih*9/16:ih:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"

Comment: @m8factorial that comes back with:

[Parsed_pad_1 @ 0x560a6a6e8e80] Input area -246:0:474:405 not within the padded area 0:0:226:404 or zero-sized
[Parsed_pad_1 @ 0x560a6a6e8e80] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_pad_1
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument

Comment: Ok, try without the operation, the size directly:
-vf "scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"

Answer (score 1):

For a landscape input, use

`-vf "scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,
      pad=iw:2*trunc(iw*16/18):(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"`

Comment: Close - i had to adjust to: -vf "scale=720x1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=iw:2*trunc(ih*16/9):(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer given by @Gyan and improved by Aaron A's efforts. I have used the solution as follows (Mac OS):

VIDEO CONTEXT: I have video of "wildlife" from an outdoor motion-sensor camera. Mostly it's prowling cats, but armadillos are the prize for my efforts. I get an overwhelming amount of useless video recordings that I cull. And then I still have hundreds of files with animal antics.

I simply need proper letterboxing that will allow me to adapt any video file that is not 16:10. I want to show ALL of the content and not cover over any of it.

CAMERA SOURCE: The files I'm working with are recorded as AVI format at 16:9 ratio for a typical landscape resolution of 1280w x 720h.

DISPLAY DEVICE: The destination is an internet-enabled digital frame using the Frameo software. It presents in a 16:10 ratio at a maximum resolution of 1280 x 800. It will automatically scale up or down content and there are preferences for displaying photos that do not apply to all videos. Some of the video content is being cut out when the software fills the frame; in this case it is cutting off content on the left and right and showing full height. Due to the design of the plastic around the screen, some of the pixels are lost behind the plastic. The software is always being updated but I cannot get it to do the letterboxing at this time.

I need to apply proper letterboxing before moving the file to the frame and I want to use ffmpeg so that I can automate to convert hundreds of short 10-sec movie files.

Here's my WORKING solution for one file.

```
ffmpeg -i SOURCE -vf scale=1280:800:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:800:'(ow-iw)/2':'(oh-ih)/2',setsar=1 DEST
```

SOURCE is a video file in AVI or mp4 formats
and DEST is my output file

I changed only the scale numbers for the output width:height to match the output I need.

1280:800

I kept the expression for dividing up the padding needed inside the single quotes.

'(ow-iw)/2' and '(oh-ih)/2'

Again, my inputs are 1280:720 but those numbers are not shown explicitly. Here's the typical math for letterboxing my input videos.

(oh-ih)/2 = (800-720)/2 = 40 pixels

For my files, nothing is added on the left and right because the ow output width and iw input width are both 1280.

Notably, this is a solution that could work if I had other types of recordings with other aspect rations that do not match 16:10. If I needed vertical letterboxing, adding bars on left and right, I could get it from this solution.

And now about this statement:
force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease

I read in other solution threads that it is necessary and I viewed the ffmpeg documentation on it here - https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale  Admittedly, I don't understand MOST of what I read in the documentation for the scale filter and cannot explain why this setting is required.

Learn more or get updates on new developments for Frameo software here.https://support.frameo.net/hc/en-us/articles/12110057465106-Supported-Media

An AUTOMATED SOLUTION for multiple video types in one folder using MacOS (NOT correct syntax for Windows). First command creates a new folder for the converted output. Second command is a for loop that looks for video extensions and applies the padding. The output file gets "_frameo" added to the filename and the whole statement converts any source file that is not  mp4 to that preferred format.

```
mkdir converted
for f in *.{mov,mp4,avi,m4v,MOV,AVI}; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf scale=1280:800:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:800:'(ow-iw)/2':'(oh-ih)/2',setsar=1 "converted/${f%.*}_frameo.mp4"; done
```